# My HTML page is not the same when i launch with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know why is there a difference when I launch my project with NodeJS and when I launch directly with the HTML file.

Here is what I am supposed to have (with the HTML file) :
[image]

And here is what I have through NodeJS :
[image]

As you can see, it seems that the VueJS variable is not working anymore.
I don't know why because, i just create a short NodeJS program to launch this HTML file. I know that it is not a huge problem and can be easily solved.

Here is my JS program

```
var http = require ('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var port = 3000

var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
  res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
  fs.readFile('index.html', function(error,data){
    if (error) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.write('Error file not found');
    }else {
      res.write(data);
    }
    res.end();
  })
})
server.listen(port,function(error){
  if(error){
    console.log('Something went wrong', error);
  }else {
    console.log("server is listening on port 3000");
  }
})
```

Thank you guys in advance for your help. I look forward to see your responses.

Comment: So there's a problem with the HTML (and/or included JS)? Which we can't see?

Comment: Can you show the client side code (including index.html file)

Comment: So **all** requests are answered with the same file? Hmm... It doesn't look like you're serving file `GS1DigitalLinkToolkit.js` (and perhaps some other dependencies) from your node server. In fact, it looks like **all** requests, no matter what path they request will be responded to with the same file. There's a bunch of info in the `req` parameter of the server callback that you're just ignoring. Don't.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, i don't know exactly where is the problem but when I included the Node server, it seems that the VueJS doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You are only serving the `index.html` file, this means that all of your dependencies (like `vue.js`) will be served as your HTML file. Take a look at the developer console in your browser and check out the errors, I'll bet some of them are complaining about an HTML content type in the response for all `<script>` tags. This is what @spender is trying to point out to you.

Comment: Your webserver only serves a single file, despite requests to it for other files. I've already tried to explain. When your webpage tries to load the script `GS1DigitalLinkToolkit.js`, it's asking your server for that file. The response that you're handing back (for this and all other possible requests) is just another copy of `index.html`... which starts with `<`, hence the error you're seeing in your answer (that shouldn't be).

Comment: @spender Thank you for your response, i just understand. How can i solve the problem ? I tried to do "app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'js'))) "  to include the JS file but it seems it is not enough.

So what can i do ? 
Thanks

Comment: @VincentTng I'm no Express expert. I'd say you have enough information to post a new question. Basically, you should have a folder full of the files that you want your webserver to serve. You need to find the directory path of that folder (`_dirname` is the directory of the current module... you **really** don't want to be serving this). Once you have this path, you need use it as the path for `app.use(express.static(thePathIJustDiscovered))`